# Limit of a Sequence (Limit Definition)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove the limit using the definition of limit of a sequence.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2n+1}{3-n^2} = 0$$

I kept trying to find a way to isolate n and have a value of N or k on my scratch work but it does not seem possible. I am a first year college student and this problem really boggles my mind.

Comment: Quoting from the dialog that appeared when you clicked "Ask Question":  "3. ... describe what you’ve tried".  So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{2n+1}{1-n^2}=\frac{2+1/n}{1/n-n}$, $1/n-n<0$ for all $n>2$, so the fraction is negative. Take small $\epsilon>0$. We can assume that $\epsilon<1$.

You need to show that for all big enough $n$, $\frac{2n+1}{1-n^2}>-\epsilon$ or $2+1/n<-\epsilon(1/n-n)=\epsilon(n-1/n)$.

Take any natural $n>10/\epsilon$. Then $2+1/n<2+\epsilon/10<3$, and $\epsilon(n-1/n)>\epsilon (10/\epsilon-\epsilon/10)>10-\epsilon^2/10>9$.
QED